# connection between client-side and server-side not working on socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have problem with socket connection between client-side and server-side .

I have this code on server-side :-

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('a user connected');

  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

and this code on client-side :-

```
<html>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.1/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

the code in server-side is working , but in client-side i have these errors :-
[image]

can anyone help me to fix problem ?
Thanks a lot :(

Comment: Any errors in browser console?

Comment: No . There are no errors in browser console

Comment: Unfortunately .. the same problem

Comment: What about server side? Can you show server messages from console?

Comment: only show this message when execute server-side file:- 
listening on *:3000

Answer (score 0):

Its looks like you are opening file directly into browser. Actually you are not specify path for serving your html. so that socketio can `POST` and poll data there.

`app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});`

If you really need to open file directly into browser rather than serving via nodejs on same port you have to specify host and port in client-side socket.

rather than simply using `io()` which will look for local port you can use this

`var socket = io("http://localhost:3000");`

Comment: The same problem .

Comment: @alial-shelleh i have tried your code and its working fine for me. try solution for client side edit.

Comment: have you added route or tried with modifying client side code. can you show which url you are trying to open.

Answer (score 0):

So here how it works for me

```
// server

const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
//                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

// here you should serve your index.html file
// and the socket io will know which socket to track
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

// client/index.html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      // here it automatically track localhost:3000
      var socket = io();
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope it will help you